# Error During deploying Spring application on Weblogic 12.1.3.0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, weblogic

I am trying to deploy an application consisting of `apache CXF`, `Spring` and `Hibernate` libraries on `weblogic` server, the application leverages the `JMS` and dataSource from `weblogic` server.

However when I am trying to deploy the application, the deployment is failing with error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I have researched this error on google but got nothing relevant to fix this. Please help me to fix this. Below is my `pom.xml` and spring `applicationContext.xml`

```
<dependencies>

<!-- CXF Dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.xjc-utils.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.1.Final</version><!-- Use the same version for EHCache -->
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate annotation -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
<version>4.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate Dependencies Above -->
<dependency>
<groupId>antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
<version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.12.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet API -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>${servletapi.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Active MQ, Weblogic JMS Dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
<version>5.15.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
<artifactId>weblogic-t3thinclient</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

===================ApplicationContext.xml========================

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wls.deployable.cxf"/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="devUserDatasource" jndi-name="jdbc/devUserDatasource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/> 


<bean id="stock" class="com.wls.deployable.cxf.stockquote.StockQuotePortTypeImpl" />

<jaxws:endpoint id="stockService" implementor="#stock" address="/StockService" />

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
<property name="environment">
<props>
<prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost:7001</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiTemplate">
<ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
</property>
<property name="jndiName">
<value>/com/jms/dev/cf</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
<property name="jndiTemplate">
<ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
</property>
<property name="cache">
<value>true</value>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
<property name="connectionFactory">
<ref bean="queueConnectionFactory" />
</property>
<property name="destinationResolver">
<ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
</property>
</bean>
```

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: We have no clue on which Spring version you use (you left that out of your question and the posted `pom.xml`). However you either are mixing jars from different spring versions or haven't specified that Weblogic should prefer `org.springframework` classes from the web app instead of the server.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for reply... below are the verision apis I am using  <cxf.version>3.2.1</cxf.version>
   <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
   <servletapi.version>3.0-alpha-1</servletapi.version>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because your web application is pulling in an older version of
spring AOP, you need to pull **spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE** which contains the missing method.

**How to get around the issue:**

Spring AOP jar is being pulled into your application dependencies as a transitive dependency. 
To see which dependency in your POM file is causing to pull spring AOP jar you can see dependency hierarchy for your web application by opening its pom file in eclipse(or other IDE) and then searching for spring-aop , once you have spotted the direct dependency in your application's POM that requires spring AOP, you need to then change its version to latest so that it would then pull correct version of sprint-aop i.e. the version which contains the missing method **org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget**

For example there is a dependency in your application's POM say **abc** which has dependency on spring AOP, you need to change the version of **abc** to latest to solve the problem.

Any queries/clarifications! Please let me know!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fahim Aslam Bhatti, I added a exclusion for spring-aop in spring-web dependency, and added spring-aop version **5.0.5.RELEASE** as a dependency separately, and it got deployed on weblogic successfully.. thanks a lot you are a saviour .!! :)

Comment: No worries, so Can you accept the answer then !

To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Comment: If you need to add an exclusion you are basically mixing versions of Spring... Which means you have more serious issues then only deployment.

Comment: If spring-web was requiring spring-aop , Could you try to just update version of spring-web to latest so that it would then pull latest spring-aop which would consequently resolve the problem ?

Comment: updating spring-web version to latest solves the problem Thanks a lot @M.Deinum andFahimAslamBhatti

Comment: Don't just update a single jar as that will result in more weird issues. You have to upgrade all Spring jars.

Comment: Yeah, that would be even better - update all spring jars

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is mostly due to JAR version conflict: another Spring AOP JAR is on the classpath before yours.